# Wordpress user id

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page that submits a form to another custom Wordpress page. I need to check the userID on this page, so I do this :

```
 $user_ID= get_current_user_id();
```

When i echo that variable I get 0. HOWEVER, if i access the page directly (without submitting the form) it shows the correct userID.

To make it stranger, when i submit the form my admin bar will disappear as if i wasn't logged in, again, if i access the page directly the admin page will appear.

What could be happening when i submit the form that will cause this?

I should mention the page im submitting to is a copy of page.php with a few lines of code to submit the variables to a database. Anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: What about outputting the information as fields with the form you are submitting? <input type="hidden" value="<?= get_current_user_id(); ?>"/>

Comment: Possibly because you try to handle the form before wordpress start your session or load the required component to check if you are indeed logged in

Comment: I considered this Dillon, but it opens up security issues with people changing the hidden field and then being able to add things as another user.